# Dynamic array formula that allows for target table expansion

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a worksheet where I copy data from Table1 to Table2.

Once I have copy-pasted the data to Table2, which sits below Table1, I select the first cell in the first column of Table2 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to select down to the last used cell. Finally, I apply a concatenation array formula that adds a suffix to the values of the related cells in Table1. I have recorded these Table2 steps as a macro.

To demonstrate, Table1 looks like this:

```
Table1

   |  A      B   C   D   E
---+-----------------------
 1 | Name    V1  V3  V3  V4
---+-----------------------
 2 | Wood    10  10  10  10
 3 | wood    28  28  28  28
 4 | tree    30  45  60  68
 5 | plastic 50  50  50  50
 6 | tree    50  50  50  50
 7 | iron    64  75  75  80
```

This is the formula I use in column A of Table2:

```
{=concatenate(A2:A7," - A")}
```

This is the result after applying it to Table2:

```
Table2

   |  A               B    C    D    E
---+-----------------------------------
25 | Wood - A        25   25   25   25
26 | wood - A        50   50   50   50
27 | tree - A        50   50   100  100
28 | plastic - A     100  100  100  100
29 | tree - A        100  100  100  100
30 | iron - A        100  100  100  100
```

Now, when I add new entries to Table1, for example in cells `A8` & `A9`:

```
Table1a

   |  A      B   C   D   E
---+-----------------------
 1 | Name    V1  V3  V3  V4
---+-----------------------
 2 | Wood    10  10  10  10
 3 | wood    28  28  28  28
 4 | tree    30  45  60  68
 5 | plastic 50  50  50  50
 6 | tree    50  50  50  50
 7 | iron    64  75  75  80
 8 | table   20  25  0   30
 9 | plastic 54  35  21  0
```

after running the recorded macro, instead of using the new range `A2:A9`, it's using the previous recorded range (`A2:A7`), resulting in the `#N/A` errors as can be seen in Table2a:

```
Table2a

   |  A               B    C    D    E
---+-----------------------------------
25 | Wood - A        25   25   25   25
26 | wood - A        50   50   50   50
27 | tree - A        50   50   100  100
28 | plastic - A     100  100  100  100
29 | tree - A        100  100  100  100
30 | iron - A        100  100  100  100
31 | #N/A            #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A
32 | #N/A            #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A
```

This is because in the array formula, the range is not dynamic, but fixed.

So, I would like a formula which auto-adjusts the range when new entries are added or deleted from Table1. Something similar to what I have in the recorded macro which selects all the cells in column A of Table2, before applying the array formula:

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R25C1"
Range("A25", Range("A25").End(xlDown)).Select
```

I was thinking of something like the following, where I provide the starting cell of Table1 and the range down to the last cell with data is worked out automatically:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=concatenate(Range("A2",Range("A2").End(xldown)).Select,""- A"")"
```

I would like a formula solution, that I can apply to all the cells. I don't want to define variables, etc, to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is as simple as:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=concatenate(A2:" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address & ","" - A"")"
```

Note that you have to convert every single quote, `"`, in the original array formula to double quotes, `""`.

The trick with the solution is to calculate the *address* of the last cell of the range, and replace the `A6` with this address. This has to be done **outside** the string, and added to the string by using the string concatenation operator `&`.

---

However, the `Application.Goto`, `Select`, and `Selection` are unnecessary.

Thus you really should use:

```
Range("A25", Range("A25").End(xlDown)).FormulaArray _
= "=concatenate(A2:" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address & ","" - A"")"
```

Another way of coding this, using `With`, would be:

```
With Range("A25", Range("A25").End(xlDown))
  .FormulaArray = "=concatenate(A2:" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address & ","" - A"")"
End With
```

Finally, a "proper" VBA solution (the one you specifically said you didn't want):

```
With Range("A2").End(xlDown)
  Range("A25", .Offset(25 - 2)).FormulaArray = "=concatenate(A2:" & .Address & ","" - A"")"
End With
```

Note that with this last solution, there is no longer a requirement to manually pre-copy the data from Table1 to Table2.

---

**ADDENDUM:**

Just realised that you were asking for a "pure" *formula* solution. If that's all you're after, then this formula works:

```
{=CONCATENATE(A2:INDEX(A1:A24,MATCH("*",A1:A24,-1))," - A")}
```

Just remember to double quote all the single quotes when converting it for use in VBA. The resulting VBA would thus look like this:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=CONCATENATE(A2:INDEX(A1:A24,MATCH(""*"",A1:A24,-1)),"" - A"")"
```

---

### X-Solution <sub><sup>(See [What is the XY problem?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377))</sup></sub>

Also just realised that you don't actually need a complicated dynamic formula if you just use a normal formula instead of an array formula.

Just select column `A` of Table2 and enter the following formula in cell `A25`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it as normal formula in all the selected cells.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," - A")
```

The VBA code for this is:

```
Selection.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,"" - A"")"
```

This formula will automatically adjust as you add or remove rows from Table1.

Of course, I would recommend using the "proper" fully automatic VBA code which doesn't require manual pre-copying:

```
Range("A25", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(25 - 2)).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,"" - A"")"
```

---

**And Finally:**

After looking at your previous questions and the supplied data in this one, the solution for columns `B`-`E` is similarly simple. The same formula is used for all those columns, entered into cell `B25` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Normal formula:

```
=IF(B2<25,25,IF(B2<50,50,100))
```

Equivalent VBA:

```
Selection.Formula = "=IF(B2<25,25,IF(B2<50,50,100))"
```

"Proper" fully-auto VBA:

```
With Range("A2").End(xlDown)
  Range("B25", .Offset(25 - 2, 4)).Formula = "=IF(B2<25,25,IF(B2<50,50,100))"
End With
```

Note that I have simplified the formula by using numbers directly instead of numbers as strings and then using `VALUE()` to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need a range in the formula that dynamically expands according to the text values in column A.

```
=concatenate(A2:index(a:a, match("zzz", a:a)), " - A")
```

In order to homogenize the numeric entries, they should use the same match formula to determine the terminating row. For column B,

```
b2:index(b:b, match("zzz", a:a))
```